# Bash syntax error: unexpected end of file on fi

Tags: bash

This is probably a simple one, but i've just started learning bash and i cant figure out the problem, the exact error is "line 37: syntax error: unexpected end of file" wich is the "fi" exit

Dont know what to look for

```
#!/bin/bash
#testfile

echo "Ingresar opción seguido de usuario"  
echo "1 - Borrar usuario"  
echo "2 - Resetear contraseña"  
echo "3 - Agregar o quiltar de grupo"  
echo "4 - Crear un usuaro"  
echo "Ej: 1 pepito"  
read n N  
if [ $n == 1 ];  
then  
    echo "userdel $N"  
    echo "Hecho."     
elif [ $n == 2 ];  
then  
    echo "passwd -e $N"  
    echo "Hecho."  
elif [ $n == 3 ];  
then  
    echo "1 - Agregar"  
    echo "2 - Quitar"  
    read g  
    if [ $g == 1 ];  
    then  
        echo "Que grupos?"  
        read f  
        echo "useradd $N $f"  
    elif [ $g == 2 ];  
    then  
        echo "Que grupos?"  
        read f  
        echo "usermod $N $f"      

    else  
        echo "no es ninguno"  
    fi
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation of your code, which makes the error perfectly clear -- you're missing a `fi` for the outer `if`...

Comment: Hey thanks both, i didnt know and i was bashing myself, i guess every fi is the end of an if, and not of the whole script? thanks again, and the site really helps

Comment: "unexpected end of file" generally means you started some sort of syntactic structure, but didn't finish it; bash ran into the end of file while it was looking for the end of the structure. In this case, it's an `if` that didn't have a matching `fi` to finish it off, but you'll get similar errors for `case` without `esac`, `while` or `for` without `done`, `(` without `)`, `{` without `}`, starting a quoted string without a matching close quote, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `fi` after the last line.
This is what the message tells you.

To fix that, simply add a line at the end, with `fi`.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "are not about programming [as defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" -- a definition that explicitly excludes questions based on typos, and questions previously asked and answered many times before.